# What is difference between "git check-ignore *" and "git ls-files --other --ignored --exclude-standard"?

Tags: git, gitignore, ignore

I'm trying to check files that are ignored by git, and I found 2 commands show same result.

which are

1. `git check-ignore *`
2. `git ls-files --others --ignored --exclude-standard`

It seems different approach, but would it show same result in any condition?

Comment: These outputs may be coincidentally identical at some point for some repo, but they may also differ. Just tried it on a repo I have here, first output is empty, second one shows about ten lines.

Comment: Remember that Git is a *set of tools*. In a good tool set, you'll have hammers, chisels, screwdrivers, box wrenches, adjustable wrenches, socket wrenches, and so on. Many of these can be used in odd ways, e.g., you can use a screwdriver as a chisel, or turn a screw with an adjustable wrench. This may sometimes (rarely) even be useful, e.g., if the screw head has been damaged.

Comment: Using the *right* tool, however, will get your work done quickly, easily, and reliably. Which tool is the *right* tool? That depends on both the tool and the circumstance, as the damaged-screw-head case suggests. In Git's case, some tools are deliberately "user oriented", like check-ignore. Git calls these *porcelain*. Others are deliberately oriented towards building larger commands from pieces, such as `git rev-parse` and `git symbolic-ref`. The ls-files command falls into this category, which Git calls *plumbing* commands.

Answer (score 4):

Although not specifically documented, the difference is that [`git check-ignore <pathname>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) doesn't recurse into subdirectories<sup>1</sup>, while [`git ls-files --others`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#Documentation/git-ls-files.txt---others) does.

Let's say that your working directory looks like this:

```
.
|-- ignored-file
|-- bin
|   |-- another-ignored-file
```

While being at the root of the working directory, if you run:

```
git check-ignore *
```

You'll get just `ignored-file`. If you run:

```
git ls-files --others --ignored --exclude-standard
```

You'll get:

```
ignored-filed
bin/another-ignored-file
```

Now, if you were to run both commands in the `bin` directory, you'll get the same output.

---

1. It's actually kind of surprising that [`git check-ignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) accepts wildcards at all, since the documentation calls the argument *pathname* and not [*pathspec*](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec). **Update:** as [@LeGEC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86072/legec) pointed out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69084527/what-is-difference-between-git-check-ignore-and-git-ls-files-other-igno/69085286?noredirect=1#comment122104541_69085286), the shell is interpreting the pathname, hence the support for wildcards.

Comment: The wildcard is handled by the shell, not by `check-ignore`. If I type `git check-ignore "*"`, I get no output.

Comment: Incidentally, the reason check-ignore doesn't recurse and ls-files does is straightforward: check-ignore is directly checking the supplied arguments (as @LeGEC notes, they are indeed pathnames and not pathspecs) while ls-files is focused on Git's index vs working tree, so it naturally reads the entire working tree.